# How to get permission for loading own website using webview in android app as application suspended

Tags: android, webview, permissions, android-webview

My app have been suspended from the google play store and the reason is that i am loading a website using a webview .Website belongs to me as i am the owner.So how to tell the google that it is my own property and now i want to launch android app.Should i have to mention it in Description .
Please help me out.

Comment: Google suspended your app Because they have no control on your website and you could potentially do everything you want on a person's phone such as stealing sensitive data or taking pictures without user's permission

Comment: No my website is just a blog .It is not stealig any sensitive data.The reason i have understood till now is that,we can't load any site .We have to tell the google that is my own and have to take the permissions .But How?

Comment: I was not saying that your site steals data. I was just saying that, as far as I know, google doesn't trusts apps containing a site because the site owner (Not necessarily you) can do everything on a person's phone without their (Google) control. Anyway I don't know how to do it. I can only suggest you to try to use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) if you want to make your blog an app. It allows you to put your site structure directly inside the app, as a site on localhost and you can create services to retrieve data from your db/host